# Can someone explain why this spacing is preferred for III-VI progression

Tags: theory, harmony, classical-music

I was studying from walter piston's harmony and came across this. Can someone explain why the first progression is unusual while the second one is preferred?

[image: unusual progression]

[image: preferred progression]

Comment: What edition is this from? I don't see it in the first edition.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis In the fifth edition, it's in Chapter 3, example 3–27, page 34.

Answer (score 7):

<sub>**Note:** All page references are to the fifth edition of Walter Piston's *Harmony* (rev. Mark DeVoto, W.W.Norton & Co., 1987).</sub>

---

Piston sets things up in Chapter 3, "Harmonic Progression in the Major Mode: Principles of Voice Leading" with his "Rule of Thumb 2":

> If the two triads have no tones in common, the upper three voices move in opposite direction to the motion of the bass, but always to the nearest available position. (26)

By this rule, the "unusual" voicing is almost perfect: there's one common tone, and all other voices move to the nearest available position.

**The key element is that the upper voices do not move in contrary motion with the bass.**

The problem with the "unusual" progression comes through Piston's discussion of "The Direct Octave and Fifth" (32 – 34).

> The prominence of [direct octaves and fifths] ..., *especially when located between the outside voices*, bass and soprano, requires special attention in elementary harmony. (32; emphasis mine)

The "unusual" voicing contains a hidden parallel octave between the bass and soprano, while the "preferred" voicing, by the upper voices moving in contrary motion with the bass, avoids it. In this case, the direct octave between bass and soprano is noticeable enough that it takes precedence over the otherwise reasonable voice leading.

---

A general comment:

In counterpoint, it's generally poor style for all moving voices to move simultaneously in the same direction, which occurs in the "unusual" voicing, but not in the "preferred".

Comment: I agree with @Aaron that the hidden octaves in the first example are its worst feature.  I would add to this two thoughts.  First, that hidden octaves are generally considered OK if one part (especially the lower) moves by skip or leap.  Mozart's "horn fifths" are an example of this.  Second, the second example is not perfect either.  There is a hidden parallel fifth between soprano and tenor.

Comment: @Aaron - In the *unusual* voicing, the motion is actually "oblique", not similar as you ascribe.

Comment: @nuggethead Horn fifths are a feature of natural brass instruments, not of Mozart's compositional style.  Mozart was certainly neither the first nor the last to employ them.

Comment: Agreed @phoog .

Comment: "Rule of thumb 2" sounds like what Piston gives for a progression like `IV V` step wise roots. I expect that edition must have a rule of thumb for one common tone, two voices move by step (root descending fourth or fifth) which would be the OP's "usual" move.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis Spot on. "Rule of Thumb 1. If two triads have one or more tones in common, these common tones are usually repeated in the same voice, the remaining voice or voices moving to the nearest tones of the second chord."

Comment: Right, so like jjmusicnotes pointed out, the progression in question is covered by that rule of thumb 1 as "usual" and "preferred" as an alternative for certain situations.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis No, because the common tones don't repeat in the same voice and the soprano doesn't move to the nearest chord tone. jjmusicnotes was just pointing out some poor wording in an earlier edit of my post.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I wonder if you're misreading "unusual" as "usual"?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I get that the book is saying to use the 'preferred'

Comment: The "unusual" example, the `E4` is held, the other two upper voices move my step. That voice leading is rule of thumb #1. The "preferred" is an alternative, and in that voice leading the common tone changes voices. I don't know how that alternative/preferred voice leading is presented in the 5th edition, but in 1st edition, all voices moving to nearest next tone, contrary to bass, is given first for root progression by step like `IV V` and later as an alternative for `II V`.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis The fifth edition presents the two voicings as given in the OP. The key element here is the "contrary to the bass" aspect. In the "unusual" voicing the upper voices and bass all move similarly, creating a soprano-bass hidden octave, which is why the second voicing is preferred.

Comment: Are you talking about example 3-27 `g`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144340/discussion-between-aaron-and-michael-curtis).

Answer (score 4):

The root progression is a descending fifth and the normal voice leading for that is *hold the common tone, move the other two voices by step.*

My first edition of Piston's *Harmony* does not have these exact examples you give (either I can't find them or you have another edition) but he addresses part of your question in the section *THE DIRECT OCTAVE AND FIFTH*.

Piston explains about the *direct octave* in the outer voices:

- it is usually avoided in upward movement
- except when the upper voice moves by a minor second, acting as a leading tone

Your "unusual" example shows a direct octave in the outer voices, and the upper voice moves by a *whole* step, and so should be avoided.

This is similar to advice he gives about `II V` (the first edition uses all upper case Roman numerals) where rather than holding the common tone Piston says to *move the upper voices down to the next available position*. This is what your "preferred" example does except on roots `III VI`.

Piston does not connect these two ideas explicitly, but `II V` does not have any half step movements, so there is some overlap in the two guidelines.

It would help to have the text that goes with your examples, because Piston seemed pretty good at explaining his ideas in both words and notation. It seems to me you could also avoid the direct octave issue by either making the bass descend or putting the tenor part `B C` into the soprano. The "preferred" solution given in example `h` may be meant to illustrate *one particular point of the text* and not the only way to voice lead `III VI`.

---

I found a copy of the 5th edition online.

The full chart for ex. 3-27 is...

[image]

The order of examples in the chart seems a little confusing to me, so I'll describe it with a slightly different order.

[image]

`a` is the *Rule of Thumb 1*, but deemed "unusual" because in `II V` when the soprano is scale degree `^4` it should descend, so `b` is "preferred" where the upper voices all descend to the next closest tones.

[image]

In terms of root progression `c` is the same as `a` and `b`, the reason that this example follows *Rule of Thumb 1* as "usual" is because the soprano is not scale degree `^4`, but `#^4` acting as a leading tone.

[image]

`g` is the application of *Rule of Thumb 1*, but deemed "unusual" because *in upward movement, the preferred motion to a direct octave is with the soprano moving by a minor second, acting as a leading tone*, so `h` is given as "preferred", because it avoids the direct octave.

[image]

`f` is the same root progression of a descending fifth which is found in all the other examples above, and is exhibits *Rule of Thumb 1*, and is deemed "acceptable despite the soprano moving by whole step and *not* acting as a leading tone.

Unless I missed something the text really doesn't explain the difference between `f` and `g`. They are the same in terms or root progression and voice leading. Except for changing the octave of the held voice, all the internals are the same, the two are just an exact transposition. The only difference is the chord and scale degree relationships to the tonic. At first the "acceptable" and "unusual" labels seem contradictory, but the difference probably lies in treatment of scale degrees.

Later in the text there is a section *Tonality and Modality* in which the importance of the various scale degrees and chords are discussed with the very broad generalization that tonal degrees are more important than, and get emphasized more than, modal degrees. `F` may be "acceptable", because the direct octave, which is a kind of emphasizing, moves to scale degree `^2`, which is generally considered tonal or between tonal and modal. By comparison `g` is a direct octave to scale degree `^6`, a modal degree that perhaps should not be emphasized. This is just my speculation, but I'm trying to keep within the overall sense of Piston's text. Scale degree function and tonal/modal distinctions are important concepts in the book.

I think some mention of the descending fifths sequence needs to be made in relation to this question. A descending fifth root progression uses the *Rule of Thumb 1* for basic voice leading. The "preferred" voice leading is an alternative to *Rule of Thumb 1* which moves the voices in a descending fashion. It is common for a descending fifths sequence to *use both voice leading patterns* in an alternating pattern. In a sequence the "rule", "unusual", and "preferred" don't apply, the two voice leading patterns are on equal footing. Sequential passages are often regarded as tonally ambiguous which removes a clear sense of scale degree identities. Those identities are a driving factor in the labeling of acceptability in example `3-27`.

Comment: Ah, I saw your question about which edition as I was logging in to update my answer.  Seeing that, it didn't dawn on me to look for an answer from you. In my edition, I don't find the comment about the soprano moving my half step. Allowing I might have missed it, that's a valuable distinction. Anyway, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Piston's book establishes the "rules" of basic harmony. In the spirit of "breaking all the rules" it would depend on what voicing came before and what came after and how that *feels* to you should you be the composer.

Comment: Yes.   Theory is descriptive,  not prescriptive.

Comment: IMO, Piston's _Harmony_ is more about essential guidelines (not rules), the main ones being: root progression, voice leading, tone doubling, scale degree function. When he deviates from those essential guidelines, it's usually for the sake of melody, and an artistic choice. "Breaking all the rules" is vague and not really how Piston talks about harmony.